# Why is hibernation performance so poor?

Tags: hibernate

Why is the hibernation performance (i.e the time taken to hibernate and wake up) on my laptop so poor with Ubuntu? This isn't a criticism *per se* but I'd be interested to know if there was a particular reason why it was so slow.

Is this a problem with every Ubuntu install?

My hardware specs:

- Intel Core i3 2.13 GHz
- 3 GB DDR3 RAM
- 320 GB HDD

HDD benchmark:

```
/dev/sda5:
 Timing buffered disk reads:   96 MB in  3.06 seconds =  31.40 MB/sec
```

Comment: Noticing this too.

Comment: I've noticed this as well. And I can't figure out why it's that way. Doesn't really matter to me, Windows is still slower waking up on my computer than Ubuntu is. :)

Comment: yes, assuming the 3GB are completely used, that's how much it should take to hibernate/resume

Comment: Suggest moving RAM swapping is the reason from comment to answer and accepting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your updates moving the entire RAM contents to swap (which is required because you need to save/restore the RAM state) would take 3*1024/31 = 99 seconds. That is probably the main time consuming operation.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't save *all* ram; just the used ram, which usually ends up being less than half.